# Which co-occurrence matrix generation method is better for a list of words?

Tags: python, nlp

I am working on a project where I need to generate a co-occurrence matrix for a given list of words. I have found two different methods for generating this matrix, but I'm not sure which one would be more suitable for my task.

The list of words I am working with is quite extensive (provided below an example), and I need to make sure that the method I choose is efficient and accurate for generating the co-occurrence matrix.

```
word_list = ['geben', 'interessieren', 'bringen', 'lassen', 'stellen', 'sehen', 'hand', 'erfahren', 'nehmen', 'steigen', 'super', 'kandidatinnen', 'veroffentlicht', 'weiß', 'kampfen', 'stehen', 'wort', 'stark', 'schließlich', 'einfach', 'sogar', 'weg', 'bleiben', 'direkt', 'gehort', 'zeigen', 'madels', 'clip_s', 'schaffen', 'begeistern', 'erklart', 'schwierig', 'kandidatin', 'wohnen', 'fragen', 'sagen', 'topmodel', 'letzt', 'backstage', 'meinung', 'erfahrung', 'selbstbewusst', 'sache', 'wichtig', 'germany', 'emotional', 'aussehen', 'fuhlt', 'freuen', 'familie', 'nathalie', 'std', 'umstyling_std', 'justine', 'casting_edition', 'tamara', 'theresia', 'maribel', 'untertitel', 'enisa', 'edition', 'modelloft', 'transformation', 'lijana', 'simone', 'tatjana', 'thoma', 'maureen', 'sayana', 'staffel_episode', 'gebardensprache', 'sendung', 'nacktshooting', 'linda', 'social', 'streit', 'sender', 'high_fashion', 'madchen', 'duellwoche', 'michael', 'jasmin', 'preview', 'makeover', 'team', 'kostenlos', 'dream_edition', 'sixx', 'bodypainting', 'nackt', 'anmelden', 'nachher', 'episode', 'celine', 'sedcard', 'anna', 'schuh', 'wasser', 'live', 'jacky', 'kostenlos', 'sender', 'anmelden', 'edition', 'high_fashion', 'transformation', 'duellwoche', 'dream_edition', 'casting_edition', 'gebardensprache', 'untertitel', 'film', 'modelloft', 'std', 'umstyling_std', 'nacktshooting', 'cover', 'ander', 'erhalten', 'hollywood', 'berlin', 'social', 'show', 'entdecken', 'fashion_week', 'tv', 'einzug', 'live', 'nachwuchsmodels', 'video', 'pose', 'shooting', 'catwalk', 'halbfinale', 'episode', 'bodypainting', 'juror', 'ansehen', 'sedcard', 'schnell', 'highlights', 'zuschauer', 'heidi_klum', 'gastjurorinnen', 'trailer', 'gntm', 'gewinnerinnen', 'madchen', 'staffel_episode', 'gast']
```

Here are the two methods I've come across:

Method 1: Custom Python code

```
    def _co_occurrence_n_gram(self, word_list, window_size):
        co_occurence_counts = defaultdict(int)
        vocab = set()

        # Iterate over the words in the word list
        for word in word_list:
            # iterate over tokens in the word
            for i, token in enumerate(word):
                vocab.add(token)  # add the token to the vocab

                # Get the next tokens within the window size
                next_tokens = word[i + 1 : i + 1 + window_size]
                for next_token in next_tokens:
                    # Create a tuple of the sorted tokens and increment the co-occurrence count
                    co_occurrence_key = tuple(sorted([next_token, token]))
                    co_occurence_counts[co_occurrence_key] += 1

        # Create a DataFrame to represent the co-occurrence counts
        vocab = sorted(vocab)  # sort eh vocab
        data_frame = pd.DataFrame(
            data=np.zeros((len(vocab), len(vocab)), dtype=np.int16), index=vocab, columns=vocab
        )

        # populate the DataFrame with the co-occurrence counte
        for co_occurrence_key, count in co_occurence_counts.items():
            data_frame.at[co_occurrence_key[0], co_occurrence_key[1]] = count
            data_frame.at[co_occurrence_key[1], co_occurrence_key[0]] = count

        return data_frame
```

Method 2: Using scikit-learn's CountVectorizer

```
    def _co_occurrence_n_gram(self, word_list):
        # Flatten the list of words
        all_words = " ".join(word_list)

        # Create a CountVectorizer with ngram_range=(1, 1) and stop_words='english'
        cv = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1))

        # Convert the list of words into a matrix of token counts
        X = cv.fit_transform([all_words])

        # Calculate the co-occurrence matrix
        Xc = X.T * X
        Xc.setdiag(0)  # Set the diagonal elements to zero

        # Get the feature names (tokens)
        names = cv.get_feature_names_out()

        # Create a DataFrame to represent the co-occurrence matrix
        data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=Xc.toarray(), columns=names, index=names)

        return data_frame
```

I want to know the differences between these two methods and which one is more suitable for generating a co-occurrence matrix for a large list of words. Specifically, I'm interested in factors like efficiency, accuracy, and ease of use.

Could someone please provide insights or recommendations on which method to choose and why? Any examples or comparisons would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!